# Trouble finding an installed version of PyAutoGui

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui, installation-package

I have been had to reinstall Anaconda and update to Python 3.6.  Because PyAutoGUI was not a standard package, I wanted to reinstall.

Because I have a Mac, I followed these steps:
1) First I installed pyobjc-framework-Quartz, 
2) Then I installed pyobjc-core
3) Then I installed pyobjc
4) Finally, I installed pyautogui.

This is what I got in my terminal window:

> BTs-MacBook-Pro:documents admin$ pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Quartz in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core>=3.2.1 in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyobjc-framework-Quartz)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-framework-Cocoa>=3.2.1 in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyobjc-framework-Quartz)
>
> BTs-MacBook-Pro:documents admin$ pip install pyobjc-core
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>
> BTs-MacBook-Pro:documents admin$ pip install pyobjc
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyObjC
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-core==3.2.1 in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyobjc)
>
> ...
>
> /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyobjc)
>
> BTs-MacBook-Pro:documents admin$ pip install pyautogui
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyautogui in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyautogui)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pymsgbox in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyautogui)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: PyTweening>=1.0.1 in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyautogui)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pyscreeze in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyautogui)
>   Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Pillow->pyautogui)

So it would appear that everything is correctly installed.  However, when I then try to import PyAutoGUI in the iPythonConsole is says

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'"

I checked the sys.path from iPythonConsole and I got this:

> ['', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python36.zip', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyObjC', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg', '/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/admin/.ipython']

I suspect that it is something dumb that I am missing, but after trying for the last few hours I would love a little help.  It has been a while since I installed this.

Thanks!